# Localized Interface builder storyboard doesn't work in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, storyboard

After updated to Swift 4.2 I tested new app version on iPhone where is a main language is Russian. Region is also Russia, but app using English Interface builder storyboard (Base). Even I have Russian one.

[image]

I also have Localizable strings for UIAlertController.

[image]

And it works. I mean, when I use my app on my iPhone (Russian language. Region is Russia) then I see English Interface builder storyboard, but alerts on Russian.

I didn't set language in scheme.

[image]

[image]

I even created new project there made 2 languages. Same problem.

Help me please where is a problem. Why iOS doesn't wanna see necessary Interface builder storyboard

Comment: @zhi-zhou I read your post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742614/base-internationalisation-with-xcode-10 Apple removed "Base.lproj" from Xcode 10? That's why I have my problem? I just need switch Base to English?

Comment: According to [https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/404/](this WWDC section) Base localization is still in charge.

Comment: Did you manage to get to the bottom of this? I noticed this issue popping up on one of my projects.

Comment: I filed a bug with apple, I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 11):

Just FYI. I had the same issue and I accidentially removed a semicolon in the Storyboard translation file.
Syntax errors in the Localizeable.strings will prevent Xcode from compiling, but NOT in in the storyboard . This will cause XCode to ignore this file and just skip this translation.

Comment: saved my hours.Thanks

Comment: holy shit you saved me tons of time. Xcode warns when semicolon is missing in a Localizable.strings file, but somewhy decided to not warn just ignore file when it's missing inin storyboard's localizable file. How stupid!

Comment: This is an insidious problem, since none of the strings that follow in that Storyboard.strings file will be colored as if anything was wrong. In my case I was missing a " and you would think that that would make all following characters on the next lines seem to be part of the string, until it reached another ".

Comment: O.M.G. I had a colon instead of a semicolon for several entries (must have copy/pasted the error several times and not noticed). No compile-time error message,  Xcode? No syntax warning? Big Fail.

Comment: son of a! dude its been an issue for a month that i spend couple of hours every couple of days trying to figure it out, that was it; strange how there is no simple error checker compiler or something from Apple for .strings

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, I have Chinese and English(Base) in my MacOS App. The App always showing the Base Storyboard in Xcode 10 while it displays correctly in Xcode 9.x.

In the Build Log View, zh-CN.lproj/Main.storyboard never shows up, that means Xcode 10 does not compile it at all.

Since I update to Xcode 10.1, the issue disappeared.
I think Apple have fixed it.